# Trilogy from 1990/2000's with men and women sword fighters

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to find a trilogy from 1990/2000's with men and women sword fighters.  The swords had some special souls in them.  At the end the man loses his sword's power while the woman is giving birth.  I have looked everywhere and can not find it.    I think the women was from the north and the man was from the desert.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the cover at all?  Do you mean to imply the sword's soul went into the baby?

Comment: Sorry, I dont remember the cover.   The Sword had a soul of some type

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Reminiscent of Jennifer Roberson's *Sword Dancer* book series. I don't remember the specific incident you describe, though it's been many years since I read them, and I .only have read the first 4 of 7.

Comment: THANK YOU!   It was Jennifer Roberson---it was driving me crazy because I was looking for the authors name and wanted to read it again

Answer (score 8):

Jennifer Roberson's *Sword Dancer* series (books published from 1986-2013) had the characters of Tiger, a sword-dancer from the South (desert area), and Del, a sword-dancer from the North (cold mountainous area).  The Northern sword dancers had some mystical aspects, including having souls bound into their swords.  The Southern ones were more straightforward fighters.  I recall that the 2 characters eventually had a child, though it's been too long for me to recall whether Tiger loses his abilities because of it.

This is the cover of the first book:

[image]

Comment: This bubbled up in my memory hours later, but I couldn't even begin to say where this book might be hiding, and it was over 30 years ago...  Nevertheless I like this answer; definitely a decent possibility.

Comment: That was the one that popped into my head as I was reading Wendy's description. (Although I think I only read the first two, and skimmed through the third, way back in the 1990s, so I'm not sure about such details as a magic sword losing its power at the same time a woman is giving birth. I suspect that only came later on, if it is in fact the same series.)